# Extending bokeh with coffeescript: fails to import libraries

Tags: coffeescript, bokeh

I'm trying to add to a back end project a special bokeh chart. I used [this link](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) to do that. Now I have custom.py file:

```
from bokeh.models import Renderer
from bokeh.util.compiler import FromFile

class CustomRenderer(Renderer):

    __implementation__ = FromFile("path_to_file/custom.coffee")
    print __implementation__.code
    ...
```

and custom.coffee file:

```
import {Renderer, RendererView} from "models/renderers/renderer"
...
```

When I launch bokeh server - a page opens in browser with '500: Internal Server Error'. And I don't know why that happens.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I could possibly try to look at this but it would require a *complete* example.

Comment: @bigreddot  It doesn't work even if files are like here (without dots of course). Somehow it doesn't want to import anything. If remove all imports and all lines related to them - everything's OK.

Comment: I understand it doesn't work. I was offering to investigate why it doesn't work. But to do that would require a complete code sample to run and debug with.

Comment: It would also help to post the complete stack trace that accompanies the `500: Internal Server Error`

Comment: @bigreddot thanks, but I've found the issue - it was about bokeh version - just installed the latest.

Comment: Glad its working!